# Can an AWS Certificate Manager SSL certificate be installed on EC2 in IIS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate from the AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) for my site.

I need to establish a HTTPS connection from my load balancer to my EC2 instances, as the application that I have on there requires HTTPS to the instance.

Is it possible to install the certificate from ACM into IIS so that I can use it for end to end HTTPS to the instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL certificates from Amazon Certificate Manager can only be used with CloudFront and Elastic Load Balancers. It cannot be installed directly on an EC2 instance.

If your app needs an SSL certificate installed, you will need to get it from another service.

Comment: Use Let's Encrypt. If the official client doesn't work well use ACME.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can attach an Amazon Certificate Manager SSL (ACM) to a website would be through a load balancer (ELB) pointing to that website

Of course, a ELB would cost more than purchasing a SSL certificate outright from a provider, but if your set up already involves a ELB or will in the near term, then ACM is the way to go.